# List all current major versions of documents

Tags: 2016, document, content-approval

I have a document library on a 2016 on premise. Content approval has been turned on, only approvers can see minor versions. I have created a custom approval workflow to handle the aaproval of the documents.

This is working perfectly fine, everything is working as one would expect.

If a user does not have permission to approve he will then only see major versions of all documents (E.g. 5.0 not 5.3).

Users who do have permission to approve will see the minor versions if present (E.g. 5.3 not 5.0).

My question is this; is it possible to create a view which only links to the major versions of a document - even if there is a minor version the users does in fact have access to?

Filtering on the approval status does not work as that will leave out all documents which does have a minor version (And as such is not approved yet) - but even if they have a minor version I want to list the latests major version to all users (Even if they can see minor versions as well).

Answer (score 0):

I hope someone can prove me wrong, but I think this a permissions issue and not a view issue and as such can't be done OOTB with views.

The only solution I can think of is to temporarily reduce permissions to contributor, or create a second account that has contribute rights.

In our environment, I have a user account and a first.last.admin account.  The admin account is a Site Collection Owner.  My user account doesn't have access (normally) to sites that I have no business on.  But I can drop it in a group to see what they see when needed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are right, right now I'm approaching a solution where I use that workflow to set a link field as a link to the major version in the history list. I'll update if that works out!